# Find the float just below a value

Tags: c#, floating-point

Say I have a float X. I want to find the largest number that is less than X and can be losslessly stored in a float.

IIRC the IEEE standard says you can do this by converting the float's bits to an int representation, subtracting one, and convert back to float.

(*edit:* this is true for positive numbers that are not NaN or inf. For negative numbers, you must add. See [Rawling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14278361/11801) for more info.)

To change between representations, I only know of C#'s (cast) operator, which truncates. That's not what I want.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: Why convert _at all_? Why not compare the `float`s directly?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.80).aspx)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Write down some example value that you have and what value you want that example to become.

Comment: From reading the question, I assume the OP wasn't to find the largest number that can be accurately represented by a floating point data type that is below a specific value.

Comment: There's a `static` method called `BitConverter.GetBytes(float)`. It lets you inspect the binary representation. You may modify the byte array (for example decrement the least significant byte) and create a new `float` with `BitConverter.ToSingle` method.

Comment: @Inisheer exactly right. I've edited the question, hope it helps.

Comment: Can you invoke C code from C#? C99 has a function nextafterf (float x, float y) that returns the next representable 'float' after x in the direction of y.

Comment: @njuffa You'd have to make a new assembly, but that's a handy function to know about. thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how you can simply turn a `float` into an `int`, change it, and then turn it back into a `float`:

```
float myFloat = 10.3f;
// Get the bytes making up the float
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(myFloat);
// Make an int out of them
int myInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
// Change it
myInt--;
// Get the bytes making up the int
bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(myInt);
// Make a float out of them
myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
// gives 10.2999992 or so
```

`BitConverter` even has this built in for the 64-bit equivalent:

```
double myDouble = 10.3;
long myLong = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(myDouble);
myLong--;
myDouble = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(myLong); // gives 10.2999999...
```

However, as [Peter Ruderman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114421/peter-ruderman) points out, a simple decrement of the underlying `int` doesn't reliably give you the next-smallest `float`.

In particular, for negative numbers, you need to *increment* the integer in order to make the float *more negative*. For `float` zero, the next smallest `int` actually corresponds to `NaN`, so you need a special case there.

Here are a couple of functions I've knocked together that should cope with these cases in general; it also looks like it sensibly travels between large numbers and positive/negative infinity, too! I've used unsafe conversions to reduce code length, but you can stick to the byte conversions above if you wish:

```
static unsafe float Increment(float f)
{
    int val = *(int*)&f;
    if (f > 0)
        val++;
    else if (f < 0)
        val--;
    else if (f == 0)
        return float.Epsilon;
    return *(float*)&val;
}
static unsafe float Decrement(float f)
{
    int val = *(int*)&f;
    if (f > 0)
        val--;
    else if (f < 0)
        val++;
    else if (f == 0)
        return -float.Epsilon; // thanks to Sebastian Negraszus
    return *(float*)&val;
}
```

As [Jeppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen) points out, you probably also want to

- Start each function with `if (float.IsNaN(f)) return f;`, so you don't accidentally increment or decrement a `NaN` and give something which is a number.
- Also consider checking the input against `float.PositiveInfinity` or `.NegativeInfinity`, since, mathematically speaking, those should probably stay constant under increment/decrement.

Comment: This won't work in all cases--in particular if the initial float is 0 or negative.

Comment: For zero, you could return `-float.Epsilon`

Comment: If you increment `MaxValue` you get `PositiveInfinity` which is good. But if you increment that, you also get into the `NaN` range. It is also possible to increment or decrement **out** of the `NaN` domain, which you might also want to handle? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format for the bit layout.

Comment: Suppose you start from positive zero (`0f`) and keep incrementing (unconditionally increment the integer). Then first you'll run through the positive subnormal numbers. Then you'll run through all normal positive numbers, the first being `1.17549435E-38` and the last being `3.40282347E+38` (max value). Then comes `PositiveInfinity`. The all the `NaN` with unset sign bit. Then after all them comes negative zero. Then the negative subnormal numbers (the one closest to zero comes first), then the negative normal ones, then negative infinity, "negative" `NaN`s, and back to positive zero again.

Comment: @Jeppe I had forgotten negative zero, I've just updated to treat it like regular zero (so sadly `De(In(-0))` gives `0`, not `-0`).

Comment: Why the need to use `else if (f == 0)`. Will a simple `else` not work correctly?

Comment: @0b101010 No, the value will fall through that `else if` and into the final `else` if it is positive infinity, negative infinity, or NaN, all of which are possible `float` values.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library routine for this, `nexttowardf(x, -INFINITY);`.

If you want to do it with your own code, you can do it natively (in IEEE 754 floating-point operations, without accessing the floating-point encoding or components) as shown below (in C).

Two versions are provided, one that uses a subnormal value in each case (might be slow on some processors) and one that uses a subnormal only if the input is small (but it has a branch). +INFINITY is not supported as an input, although support could be added with a simple test. This is written for `double`, but the changes for `float` are straightforward.

If `CompileMain` is defined, it also includes a test program.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>


/*  Return the next floating-point value before the finite value q.

    This was inspired by Algorithm 3.5 in Siegfried M. Rump, Takeshi Ogita, and
    Shin'ichi Oishi, "Accurate Floating-Point Summation", _Technical Report
    05.12_, Faculty for Information and Communication Sciences, Hamburg
    University of Technology, November 13, 2005.
*/
double NextBefore(double q)
{
    // SmallestPositive is the smallest positive floating-point number.
    static const double SmallestPositive = DBL_EPSILON * DBL_MIN;

    /*  Scale is .625 ULP, so multiplying it by any significand in [1, 2)
        yields something in [.625 ULP, 1.25 ULP].
    */
    static const double Scale = 0.625 * DBL_EPSILON;

#if 0
    /*  This version has a branch but uses subnormal values only if q is so
        small that q * Scale is subnormal.
    */
    double increment = fabs(q)*Scale;

    if (0. == increment)
        return q - SmallestPositive;

    return q - increment;
#else
    /*  This version uses a subnormal, SmallestPositive, in each case.
        This might cause poor performance on some processors.
    */
    return q - fmax(SmallestPositive, fabs(q)*Scale);
#endif
}


#if defined CompileMain


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define NumberOf(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof *(a))


int main(void)
{
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    static const struct { double in, out; } cases[] =
    {
        { -INFINITY,                -INFINITY                },
        { -0x1.fffffffffffffp1023,  -INFINITY                },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffep1023,  -0x1.fffffffffffffp1023  },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffdp1023,  -0x1.ffffffffffffep1023  },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffcp1023,  -0x1.ffffffffffffdp1023  },
        { -0x1.0000000000003p1023,  -0x1.0000000000004p1023  },
        { -0x1.0000000000002p1023,  -0x1.0000000000003p1023  },
        { -0x1.0000000000001p1023,  -0x1.0000000000002p1023  },
        { -0x1.0000000000000p1023,  -0x1.0000000000001p1023  },

        { -0x1.fffffffffffffp1022,  -0x1.0000000000000p1023  },

        { -0x1.fffffffffffffp1,     -0x1.0000000000000p2     },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffep1,     -0x1.fffffffffffffp1     },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffdp1,     -0x1.ffffffffffffep1     },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffcp1,     -0x1.ffffffffffffdp1     },
        { -0x1.0000000000003p1,     -0x1.0000000000004p1     },
        { -0x1.0000000000002p1,     -0x1.0000000000003p1     },
        { -0x1.0000000000001p1,     -0x1.0000000000002p1     },
        { -0x1.0000000000000p1,     -0x1.0000000000001p1     },

        { -0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022, -0x1.0000000000000p-1021 },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffep-1022, -0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022 },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffdp-1022, -0x1.ffffffffffffep-1022 },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffcp-1022, -0x1.ffffffffffffdp-1022 },
        { -0x1.0000000000003p-1022, -0x1.0000000000004p-1022 },
        { -0x1.0000000000002p-1022, -0x1.0000000000003p-1022 },
        { -0x1.0000000000001p-1022, -0x1.0000000000002p-1022 },
        { -0x1.0000000000000p-1022, -0x1.0000000000001p-1022 },

        { -0x0.fffffffffffffp-1022, -0x1.0000000000000p-1022 },
        { -0x0.ffffffffffffep-1022, -0x0.fffffffffffffp-1022 },
        { -0x0.ffffffffffffdp-1022, -0x0.ffffffffffffep-1022 },
        { -0x0.ffffffffffffcp-1022, -0x0.ffffffffffffdp-1022 },
        { -0x0.0000000000003p-1022, -0x0.0000000000004p-1022 },
        { -0x0.0000000000002p-1022, -0x0.0000000000003p-1022 },
        { -0x0.0000000000001p-1022, -0x0.0000000000002p-1022 },
        { -0x0.0000000000000p-1022, -0x0.0000000000001p-1022 },

        { +0x1.fffffffffffffp1023,  +0x1.ffffffffffffep1023  },
        { +0x1.ffffffffffffep1023,  +0x1.ffffffffffffdp1023  },
        { +0x1.ffffffffffffdp1023,  +0x1.ffffffffffffcp1023  },
        { +0x1.0000000000004p1023,  +0x1.0000000000003p1023  },
        { +0x1.0000000000003p1023,  +0x1.0000000000002p1023  },
        { +0x1.0000000000002p1023,  +0x1.0000000000001p1023  },
        { +0x1.0000000000001p1023,  +0x1.0000000000000p1023  },

        { +0x1.0000000000000p1023,  +0x1.fffffffffffffp1022  },

        { +0x1.0000000000000p2,     +0x1.fffffffffffffp1     },
        { +0x1.fffffffffffffp1,     +0x1.ffffffffffffep1     },
        { +0x1.ffffffffffffep1,     +0x1.ffffffffffffdp1     },
        { +0x1.ffffffffffffdp1,     +0x1.ffffffffffffcp1     },
        { +0x1.0000000000004p1,     +0x1.0000000000003p1     },
        { +0x1.0000000000003p1,     +0x1.0000000000002p1     },
        { +0x1.0000000000002p1,     +0x1.0000000000001p1     },
        { +0x1.0000000000001p1,     +0x1.0000000000000p1     },

        { +0x1.0000000000000p-1021, +0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022 },
        { +0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022, +0x1.ffffffffffffep-1022 },
        { +0x1.ffffffffffffep-1022, +0x1.ffffffffffffdp-1022 },
        { +0x1.ffffffffffffdp-1022, +0x1.ffffffffffffcp-1022 },
        { +0x1.0000000000004p-1022, +0x1.0000000000003p-1022 },
        { +0x1.0000000000003p-1022, +0x1.0000000000002p-1022 },
        { +0x1.0000000000002p-1022, +0x1.0000000000001p-1022 },
        { +0x1.0000000000001p-1022, +0x1.0000000000000p-1022 },

        { +0x1.0000000000000p-1022, +0x0.fffffffffffffp-1022 },
        { +0x0.fffffffffffffp-1022, +0x0.ffffffffffffep-1022 },
        { +0x0.ffffffffffffep-1022, +0x0.ffffffffffffdp-1022 },
        { +0x0.ffffffffffffdp-1022, +0x0.ffffffffffffcp-1022 },
        { +0x0.0000000000004p-1022, +0x0.0000000000003p-1022 },
        { +0x0.0000000000003p-1022, +0x0.0000000000002p-1022 },
        { +0x0.0000000000002p-1022, +0x0.0000000000001p-1022 },
        { +0x0.0000000000001p-1022, +0x0.0000000000000p-1022 },
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOf(cases); ++i)
    {
        double in = cases[i].in, expected = cases[i].out;
        double observed = NextBefore(in);
        printf("NextBefore(%a) = %a.\n", in, observed);
        if (! (observed == expected))
        {
            printf("\tError, expected %a.\n", expected);
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    return status;
}


#endif  // defined CompileMain
```

Comment: That seems a good answer, but I am looking for a C# solution.