# Why does adding double.epsilon to a value result in the same value, perfectly equal?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, double, double-precision, epsilon

I have a unit test, testing boundaries:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
public void CreateExtent_InvalidTop_ShouldThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
{
    var invalidTop = 90.0 + Double.Epsilon;
    new Extent(invalidTop, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

public static readonly double MAX_LAT = 90.0;

public Extent(double top, double right, double bottom, double left)
{
    if (top > GeoConstants.MAX_LAT)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("top"); // not hit
}
```

I thought I'd just tip the 90.0 over the edge by adding the minimum possible positive double to it, but now the exception is not thrown, any idea why?

When debugging, I see top as coming in as 90, when it should be 90.00000000.... something.

**EDIT:**
I should have thought a bit harder, `90+Double.Epsilon` will lose its resolution. Seems the best way to go is do some bit shifting.

**SOLUTION:**

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
public void CreateExtent_InvalidTop_ShouldThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
{
    var invalidTop = Utility.IncrementTiny(90); // 90.000000000000014
    // var sameAsEpsilon = Utility.IncrementTiny(0);
    new Extent(invalidTop, 0, 0, 0);
}

/// <summary>
/// Increment a double-precision number by the smallest amount possible
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">double-precision number</param>
/// <returns>incremented number</returns>
public static double IncrementTiny(double number)
{
    #region SANITY CHECKS
    if (Double.IsNaN(number) || Double.IsInfinity(number))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("number");
    #endregion

    var bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(number);

    // if negative then go opposite way
    if (number > 0)
        return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits + 1);
    else if (number < 0)
        return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits - 1);
    else
        return Double.Epsilon;
}

/// <summary>
/// Decrement a double-precision number by the smallest amount possible
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">double-precision number</param>
/// <returns>decremented number</returns>
public static double DecrementTiny(double number)
{
    #region SANITY CHECKS
    if (Double.IsNaN(number) || Double.IsInfinity(number))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("number");
    #endregion

    var bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(number);

    // if negative then go opposite way
    if (number > 0)
        return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits - 1);
    else if (number < 0)
        return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(bits + 1);
    else
        return 0 - Double.Epsilon;
}
```

This does the job.

Comment: Double precision is a nasty business, but when comparing the maximum deviation between A and B is `Double.Epsilon`, so you've probably not tipped it enough by a very, very small margin.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411392/double-epsilon-for-equality-greater-than-less-than-less-than-or-equal-to-gre

Comment: Interesting article here: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/01/05/double-epsilon-dbl_epsilon/  The TL;DR is "`Double.Epsilon` isn't as useful as you might think!"

Comment: Bruce Dawson has [a great series of articles on ULPs and comparing floats and doubles](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/). His example code tends to be in C++ but the articles are mostly explanation.

Comment: This is probably fine for your purposes (though I'm not sure it works correctly if you want to do the equivalent test for a negative value), but people adapting it for other purposes should consider: Does this function behave reasonably when presented with infinity, nan, maxvalue, zero, denormalized, or negative numbers, and if not, do you care?

Comment: Read "_What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic_", or any of the various related discussions that appear when you Google that.

Comment: It doesn't -- the equality check just returns true for incredibly small deviations (even deviations much bigger than `double.Epsilon`).  This is part of IEE754.  (It's also why "-0" and "+0" compare as equal even though they're defined is being different in binary, and treated differently in division.)

Comment: (^ It's also the reason why `double.Epsilon == 0d` returns true.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Per [the documentation of `Double.Epsilon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.double.epsilon):

> The value of the Epsilon property reflects the smallest positive
>   `Double` value that is significant in numeric operations or comparisons
>   **when the value of the `Double` instance is zero**.

(Emphasis mine.)

Adding it to 90.0 does not produce "the next smallest value after 90.0", this just yields 90.0 again.

Comment: There's not one number that works in any situation.  `double` has a maximum of 15 digits of precision, so a tiny number that can be added to 1 and result a "different" `double` can't be added to 1,000,000 and still get a "different" `double`.

Comment: @Muhammad: That's a question all on its own. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155378/how-to-alter-a-float-by-its-smallest-increment-or-close-to-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278248/find-the-float-just-below-a-value .

Answer (score 21):

`Double.Epsilon` is the smallest positive representable value. Just because it's representable on its own does not mean it's the smallest value between any *other* representable value and the next highest one.

Imagine you had a system to represent just integers. You can represent any integer to 5 significant figures, along with a scale (e.g. in the range 1-100).

So these values are exactly representable, for example

- 12345 (digits=12345, scale = 0)
- 12345000 (digits=12345, scale = 3)

In that system, the "epsilon" value would be 1... but if you add 1 to 12345000 you'd still end up with 12345000 because the system couldn't represent the exact result of 12345001.

Now apply the same logic to `double`, with all its intricacies, and you get a much smaller epsilon, but the same general principle: a value which is distinct from zero, but still can end up not making any difference when added to larger numbers.

Note that much larger values have the same property too - for example, if `x` is a very large `double`, then `x + 1` may well be equal to `x` because the gap between two "adjacent" doubles becomes more than 2 as the values get big.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: Where are you seeing `double.Epsilon == 0d` returning true? It doesn't for me.

Comment: you're right! -- I swear it did a minute ago in a Console.WriteLine test, but it's definitely not right now -- too late to edit that comment, so I deleted it -- don't want to confuse anyone.  Double checking [IEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Comparing_floating-point_numbers) right now to get my head on straight.

Answer (score 2):

In C99 and C++, the function that does what you were trying to do is called [`nextafter`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nextafter.html) and is in `math.h`.  I do not know if C# has any equivalent, but if it does, I would expect it to have a similar name.

Answer (score 1):

Because Double.Epsilon is the "smallest noticeable change" (loosely speaking) in a double number.

.. but this **does not mean** that it will have any effect when you use it.

As you know, floats/doubles vary in their resolution depending on the magnitude of the vlue they contain. For example, artificial:

- ...
- -100 ->   +-0.1
- -10 ->   +-0.01
- 0 ->   +-0.001
- 10 ->   +-0.01
- 100 ->    +-0.1
- ...

If the resolutions were like this, the Epsilon would be `0.001`, as it's the smallest possible change. But what would be the expected result of `1000000 + 0.001` in such system?

Comment: "Double.Epsilon is the smallest noticeable change in a double number" Not exactly true - it's the smallest double _greater than 0_ that can be represented as a `double`.  There is no `double` value that that can be subtracted from 1.0 that will result in an answer equal to `double.Epsilon`

Comment: @DStanley: Thanks, added a clarification on that. I never meant to explain this part, just wanted to set readers' mind on the topic.