# Find minimum float greater than a double value

Tags: c#, c++, c, floating-point

I was having an issue with the CUDNN_BN_MIN_EPSILON value being used in the `cudnnBatchNormalizationForwardTraining` function (see [the docs here](http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html#cudnnBatchNormalizationForwardTraining)), and it turns out it was because I was passing the `float` value `1e-5f` instead of double (I'm working with `float` values to save memory and speed up computation), and this value once converted to float was slightly less than `1e-5`, which is the actual value of that constant.

After some trial and error, I found a decent approximation I'm now using:

```
const float CUDNN_BN_MIN_EPSILON = 1e-5f + 5e-13f;
```

I'm sure there's a better way to approach problems like this, so the question is:

> Given a positive `double` value, what is the best (as in "reliable") way to find the minimum possible `float` value which (on its own and if/when converted to `double`) is strictly greater than the initial `double` value?

Another way to formulate this problem is that, given a `double` value `d1` and a `float` value `f1`, `d1 - (float)f1` should be the minimum possible **negative** value (as otherwise it'd mean that `f1` was *less* than d1, which is not what we're looking for).

I did some basic trial and error (using `1e-5` as my target value):

```
// Check the initial difference
> 1e-5 - 1e-5f
2,5262124918247909E-13 // We'd like a small negative value here

// Try to add the difference to the float value
> 1e-5 - (1e-5f + (float)(1e-5 - 1e-5f))
2,5262124918247909E-13 // Same, probably due to approximation

// Double the difference (as a test)
> 1e-5 - (1e-5f + (float)((1e-5 - 1e-5f) * 2))
-6,5687345259044915E-13 // OK
```

With this approximation, the final `float` value is `1,00000007E-05`, which looks fine.

**But**, that `* 2` multiplication was completely arbitrary on my end, and I'm not sure it'll be reliable or the optimum possible thing to do there.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**: this is the (bad) solution I'm using now, will be happy to replace it with a better one!

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the minimum possible upper <see cref="float"/> approximation of the given <see cref="double"/> value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The value to approximate</param>
public static float ToApproximatedFloat(this double value)
    => (float)value + (float)((value - (float)value) * 2);
```

---

**SOLUTION**: this is the final, correct implementation (thanks to John Bollinger):

```
public static unsafe float ToApproximatedFloat(this double value)
{
    // Obtain the bit representation of the double value
    ulong bits = *((ulong*)&value);

    // Extract and re-bias the exponent field
    ulong exponent = ((bits >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 1023 + 127;

    // Extract the significand bits and truncate the excess
    ulong significand = (bits >> 29) & 0x7FFFFF;

    // Assemble the result in 32-bit unsigned integer format, then add 1
    ulong converted = (((bits >> 32) & 0x80000000u)
                        | (exponent << 23)
                        | significand) + 1;

    // Reinterpret the bit pattern as a float
    return *((float*)&converted);
}
```

Comment: Please specify your language. There is a library function for this in C++ for example. Don't know about the rest.

Comment: what about looking at the memory representation of the double, cutting the bits down to float, and then adding 1 to the least significant bit?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm working in C# (using cuDNN through a wrapper), but I was looking for a general, standalone solution (in order to understand it too, instead of just using a helper library).

Comment: @Sergio0694 Wouldn't [tag:language-agnostic] be a better tag then?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yup, I honestly didn't knew that tag, my bad 

Comment: @Aganju That sounds great, any help with that? I'm not that confident working with the bitwise representation of a floating point number.

Comment: sorry, me neither, or I would have made it an _answer_. So I only threw the idea out; someone will probably know how.

Comment: Are you sure that going to the trouble to use `float` instead of `double` is really a significant win for you?  There is certainly a space savings, but is it enough to matter?  There is not necessarily a significant performance advantage, so have you tested?

Comment: @JohnBollinger In my case I'm quite sure it's worth the trouble here, I'm working on a neural network library ([here](https://github.com/Sergio0694/NeuralNetwork.NET)) and using `double` everywhere would (unsurprisingly) double the GPU/RAM memory usage everywhere, not to mention the much increased training time for large networks.

Comment: In any case, although you have not explained in any detail how you're using the epsilon you're choosing, the name suggests judging approximate equality of FP values.  For that purpose, it's important to take into account the fact that the distance to the nearest representable neighbor of floating-point value *x* depends on *x*.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid library routines?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Both because I'm working in C# and I don't have direct access to some standard C/C++ functions, and most importantly because I'd like to actually understand the method used to solve this (ie. the bitwise operations etc..) instead of just using an external function in a black-box fashion.

Comment: There is a “next before” instead of “next after” implementation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14279976/298225). It is written in C for `double` and uses some simple library routines that are easily replaced (`fabs`, `fmax`). The constants are easily changed for `float` (`DBL_EPSILON` to `FLT_EPSILON`), and the direction can easily be changed.

Comment: You've tagged this [language-agnostic], but now you seem to be asking about approaches that depend intimately on the machine representations of types.  That's not only not language-agnostic, it's not even *implementation*-agnostic for any given language.

Comment: In macOS, `nexttowardf` is implemented by checking for domain issues and then adding (or subtracting) one to the underlying bits in the floating-point encoding. That works because the floating-point encoding is designed so that successive representable values have consecutive encodings, except at +0 and −0. That sort of bit tinkering should be avoided in normal code, which is one reason it is in a library routine.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah you're right, in fact I originally hadn't put that tag there (see the first comments here), I shouldn't have changed my mind there.

Comment: By posting your answer in the question, this has, in effect, vandalized your own post.  Better to restore your question without an answer and post your own answer as an _answer_.

Comment: Note that in C, `(ulong*)&value` is potentially UB  (C11dr §6.3.2.3 7).  Curious code did not use the `memcpy()` suggested by @John Bollinger

Comment: @chux I didn't post a separate answer because I've just copied the answer by John (the one marked as valid). I've put the code at the end of the question as well just for future reference.

Comment: @chux I couldn't find the section you mentioned (6.2.3 7), what would be the undefined behavior in that assignment? Note that my implementation is in C# and it works fine there, but I'd be interested to know what problems would there be if I were using C. And of course, in that case I could just fall back to `memcpy` as in the original answer.

Comment: " I've put the code at the end of the question as well just for future reference." is not how SO works.  Answers belong in answers, not the question so they be rated like the others.  Post should be rolled back to the pre-answer state.

Comment: Cite was not in 6.2.3 7, but 6.3.2.3 7.  "If the
resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inasmuch as you seem interested in the representation-level details, you'll be dependent on the representations of types `float` and `double`.  In practice, however, it is very likely that that comes down to the basic "binary32" and "binary64" formats of [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).  These have the general form of one sign bit, several bits of biased exponent, and a bunch of bits of significand, including, for normalized values, one *implicit* bit of significand.

### Simple case

Given a `double` in IEEE-754 binary64 format whose value is no less than +2<sup>-126</sup>, what you want to do is

- obtain the bit pattern of the original `double` value in a form that can be directly examined and manipulated.  For example, as an unsigned 64-bit integer.

  ```
  double d = 1e-5;
  uint64_t bits;
  memcpy(&bits, &d, 8);
  ```
- extract and re-bias the exponent field

  ```
  uint64_t exponent = ((bits >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 1023 + 127;
  ```
- extract the significand bits and truncate the excess

  ```
  uint64_t significand = (bits >> 29) & 0x7fffff;
  ```
- assemble the result in 32-bit unsigned integer format

  ```
  uint32_t float_bits = ((bits >> 32) & 0x80000000u)
          | (exponent << 23)
          | significand;
  ```
- add one.  Since you want a result strictly greater than the original `double`, this is correct regardless of whether all of the truncated significand bits were 0.  It will correctly increment the exponent field if the addition overflows the significand bits.  It may, however, produce the bit pattern of an infinity.

  ```
  float_bits += 1;
  ```
- store / copy / reinterpret the bit pattern as that of a `float`

  ```
  float f;

  memcpy(&f, &float_bits, 4);
  ```

### Negative numbers

Given a negative `double` in binary64 format whose magnitude is no less than 2<sup>-126</sup>, follow the above procedure except subtract 1 from `float_bits` instead of adding one.  Note that for exactly -2<sup>-126</sup>, this produces a subnormal binary32 (see below), which is the correct result.

### Zeroes and very small numbers, including subnormals

IEEE 754 provides reduced-precision representations of non-zero numbers of very small magnitude.  Such representations are called *subnormal*.  Under some circumstances the minimum binary32 exceeding a given input binary64 is a subnormal, including for some inputs that are not binary64 subnormals.

Also, IEEE 754 provides signed zeroes, and -0 is a special case: the minimum binary32 strictly greater than -0 (either format) is the smallest positive subnormal number.  Note: not +0, because according to IEEE 754, +0 and -0 compare equal via the normal comparison operators.  The minimum positive, nonzero, subnormal binary32 value has bit pattern 0x00000001.

The binary64 values subject to these considerations have biased binary64 exponent fields with values less than or equal to the difference between the binary64 exponent bias and the binary32 exponent bias (896).  This includes those with biased exponents of exactly 0, which characterize binary64 zeroes and subnormals.  Examination of the rebiasing step in the simple-case procedure should lead you to conclude, correctly, that that procedure will produce the wrong result for such inputs.

Code for these cases is left as an exercise.

## Infinities and NaNs

Inputs with all bits of the biased binary64 exponent field set represent either positive or negative infinity (when the binary64 significand has no bits set) or a not-a-number (NaN) value.  Binary64 NaNs and positive infinity should convert to their binary32 equivalents.  Negative infinity should perhaps convert to the negative binary32 value of greatest magnitude.  These need to be handled as special cases.

Code for these cases is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried using this method, but unfortunately calling it with `1e-5` gives back `1.38277519e-05f`, which doesn't seem to be the right answer, as the approximated method I wrote in the question returns just `1,00000007e-05f`, which is definitely smaller, but still valid as it's greater than the input value. Any idea why this is happening? I'll post the implementation in the question too, just to be sure I didn't make mistakes rewriting it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sergio0694, I was a little fast and loose with my description of the procedure.  If you copied my expressions exactly, as it appears you did, then you are probably suffering from an operator precedence issue in the computation of the exponent bits.  I have updated the answer by inserting parentheses where appropriate.  It works.  In particular, it computes the nearest float exceeding 1e-5 (converted back to double) as 1.00000006568735e-05, in agreement with your result.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've updated my code and the code in the edit at the end of the question, it works perfectly now! 

Comment: For negative numbers, you need to reverse the direction. And for −0, you need to jump to the minimum positive subnormal.

Comment: Right you are, @chux.  I have updated to discuss the various special cases, including subnormals, and also the not-so-special case of negative inputs.  I opt at this point not to provide complete code for all the special cases, though I do describe how to recognize them.

Answer (score 4):

In C:

```
#include <math.h>

float NextFloatGreaterThan(double x)
{
    float y = x;
    if (y <= x) y = nexttowardf(y, INFINITY);
    return y;
}
```

If you do not want to use library routines, then replace `nexttowardf(y, INFINITY)` above with `-NextBefore(-y)`, where `NextBefore` is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14279976/298225) and modified:

- Change `double` to `float` and `DBL_` to `FLT_`.
- Change `.625` to `.625f`.
- Replace `fmax(SmallestPositive, fabs(q)*Scale)` with `SmallestPositive < fabs(q)*Scale ? fabs(q)*Scale : SmallestPositive`.
- Replace `fabs(q)` with `(q < 0 ? -q : q)`.

(Obviously, the routine could be converted from `-NextBefore(-y)` to `NextAfter(y)`. That is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: Nice.  I did not previously know about `nexttowardf()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually looking for a solution that doesn't depend on any specific library/method, something that could be used in both C/C++/C#/similar. 
And yeah, just to be sure I'd like the `float` value _strictly greater_ than the given `double`.

Comment: @Sergio0694 You are not looking for a library specific, but am looking for a floating point format specific one?

Comment: Code _does_ handle sub-normals correctly as well as negative numbers. unlike the accepted answer.