# How do you find the largest float below some value?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

Given a float `x`, I would like to find the largest floating point number that is less than `x`. How can I do this in Python?

I've tried subtracting machine epsilon from `x` (`x - numpy.finfo(float).eps`), but this evaluates to `x` for sufficiently large floats, and I need the value I get back to be strictly less than `x`.

There's some information about how to do this in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278248/find-the-float-just-below-a-value), but I have no idea how to do the same bitwise conversion in Python. Anybody know how to do this, or have another method for getting the same value?

(Bigger-picture problem -- I'm trying to numerically find the root of an equation with a singularity at `x`, within the bounds `0 < root < x`. The solver (Scipy's toms748 implementation) evaluates on the boundaries, and it can't handle nan or inf values, so I can't give it exactly `x` as a bound. I don't know how close the root might be to the bound, so I want to give a bound as close to `x` as possible without actually producing an infinite value and crashing the solver.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are describing the basic usage of [`numpy.nextafter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nextafter.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.nextafter(1.5, 0.0)  # biggest float smaller than 1.5
1.4999999999999998
>>> np.nextafter(1.5, 2.0)  # smallest float bigger than 1.5
1.5000000000000002
```